# Creating a Dynamic iCal using MySQL databases in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, dynamic, icalendar

I am trying to create a dynamic iCal file for each event in my database depending on which event is currently being looked at, but for some reason it's not working.  Any ideas?

```
$current_event = $db->GetRow(false, "SELECT * FROM event WHERE eventid = ".$_GET['eventid']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM event WHERE eventid = '". $current_event['eventid'] ."'";
$data = $db->Query($sql);
$regdata = $db->GetRow($data);

$ical = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20101231T230000
DTEND:20110101T01000
SUMMARY:TOO
LOCATION:Downtown
DESCRIPTION:".$current_event['eventid']."
SEQUENCE:0
DTSTAMP:20101125T112600
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
";

header("Content-Type: text/calendar;");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=eventtooutlook.ics");
echo $ical;
exit;
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Does the file never download? Is it an invalid ics? Have you tried it on different calendar apps? What have you tried yet?

Comment: Currently I click the link to this file and it does absolutely nothing, it brings up a 404'd page even though its definitely the proper page.

Comment: Could you just pretty much empty the file and do a `echo "Hi OhCaN!";`? That would rule out the problem is the code.

Comment: When I put a simple echo command in, it functions fine, when the headers and iCal echo is there, it still works fine (when the event is hardcoded and not dynamic).

Comment: Interesting, now it downloads (thanks to anmari's help), but when I try to open it with outlook it kicks back an error stating: Cannot import vCalendar file. This error can appear if you have attempted to save a recurring Lunar appointment in iCalendar format. To avoid this error, set the appointment option to Gregorian instead of Lunar. I tried looking up solutions, but I have yet to find one that works...I added UID, changed version to 1.0 and added that zero to DTEND....still not sure what else I can do.

Answer (score 0):

Also try outputting first

header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");

I had a weird problem where my code was fine on local server, but then on remote server either got a 404 or 500 depending what I did, until i changed from

header('OK', true, 200) to the above code.

Cause maybe due to Versions of php - anyway you don't have a status header so  maybe that is it?

(aside: also your DTEND is missing a 0 )

Comment: Interesting, now it downloads, but when I try to open it with outlook it kicks back an error stating: Cannot import vCalendar file. This error can appear if you have attempted to save a recurring Lunar appointment in iCalendar format.
To avoid this error, set the appointment option to Gregorian instead of Lunar.

I tried looking up solutions, but I have yet to find one that works...I added UID, changed version to 1.0 and added that zero to DTEND....still not sure what else I can do.

Comment: Have you tried putting the file through one of the ical validator tools? eg http://severinghaus.org/projects/icv/